# PHP search form not working with .htaccess

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I have search country form with code:

```
 <form name="form_search" id="form_search" class="form1" method="get" action="country/search"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-7">
<label>Select country</label>
<div class="select1_inner">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="select2 select" style="width: 100%" name="q" id="q">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) :
$country_name=$row['country_name']; 
?>
<option value=<?php echo $country_name?>><?php echo $country_name?></option>
<?php endwhile;?> 
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

At the frontend `url` will show : http://example.com/country/search?q=parameter

but I would redirect that `url` to real directory at the backend http://example.com/page.php?module=search&id1=$1

with .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 Options -Indexes
 rewriteRule ^country/search$  page.php?module=search&id1=$1  [L]
```

But this is not working I can't get value `q` parameter

Please help me how configure .htaccess for this form

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^country/search$ page.php?module=search&id1=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Line 1: test if query string containing `q={any_characters}`

Line 2: if the url is `country/search`, redirect to `page.php?module=search&id1={any_characters}` permanently

Comment: Thank you ben, i was follow the code but after process  page showing Access forbidden!Error 403

Comment: you should add `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Ok its working now, thanks ben,  but my url became http://example.com/page.php?module=search&id1=parameter     not  http://example.com/country/search?q=parameter, http://example.com/page.php?module=search&id1=parameter its sure be at the backend not frontend url

Comment: You should change the RewriteRule Flags, to `[QSA,L]`, instead of `[R=301]`